# EF5 Code-First - Create new table

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework

I'm working with asp.net mvc3 & Entity Framework5.

My database has been designed with the Code-First.

Entity Code

```
public class User 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}

public class EFDbContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } 
}
```

Create DB Option

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFDbContext>());
```

I use this option, the database has been created.

After the database has been created, I need a Role table was.

So I had to modify the code as follows.

Entity Code

```
public class User 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}

public class Role
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}

public class EFDbContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

I use Create DB Option again.

In this case, the existing Users table will be deleted after regeneration.

I would like to be added to the Role table, but leave data in the table Users.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use Code-First Migrations.

```
Database.SetInitializer(null);
```

Then in `Package Manager Console` write:

```
add-migration addedRoles
```

If you did't enabled migrations before, You must enable it first:

```
enable-migrations
```

and last:

```
update-database
```

Complete guid:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621

**Edit**

If you want the database to be upgraded automatically whenever you run the application, you can use `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<EFDbContext, Configuration>());
```

Comment: I believe for migrations to be applied from code (not manually), you have to use the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer.

Comment: Thank you. Migration is successful you provided.

Comment: However, I have some questions.

Comment: 'Update-database-Verbose' I don't know whether this command to perform some action.This command, what does it mean?

Comment: It's `update-database -verbose` (there is a space after 'database'). It tells the EF: "Show me the SQL statements you are executing on my database"

Answer (score 0):

Learn how migrations work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

They have another initializer, `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`. In contrast to the one you use, this one will automatically upgrade your database to latest version without recreating the whole database.